# Best Way to Keep Page View Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pageviews

I'll be keeping details of PageView counts for a specific table.

Table design is:

```
[IMAGE_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[IMAGE_PATH] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[CARTOON_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ADD_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[ADD_USER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[IMAGE_TEXT] [nvarchar](max) NULL
```

I'll be showing these images on each page and need the best way to keep the unique page view counts.

How would you do it?

Please remember that this table will have around 10000 images in short time and will a lot of activity. Updating this table on each request doesn't seem clever to me.

Comment: I've done this before by keeping the View count in the Application and periodically updating to the database in batches.

Comment: How were you keeping it in Application? Were you saving the details on the server(in a text file or something)

Comment: In a collection in memory in the application. Obviously it meant that in the event of an application restart some views would be lost but that wasn't particularly critical for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the best way is to keep a temp table with

```
IMAGE_ID
IP_ADDRESS
VISIT_DATE
```

and a view table that keeps

```
IMAGE_ID
COUNTER
```

And batch update the view table with the details of temp table and clear the content of it periodically.